# Unable to install PyGObject on a mac

Tags: python, pycharm

I am having problems trying to install `PyGObject` on a mac:

```
Collecting PyGObject
  Using cached pygobject-2.28.3.tar.bz2
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/pb/4p0s32g54dl1vg3s25kch71w0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/PyGObject/setup.py", line 272
        raise SystemExit, 'ERROR: Nothing to do, gio could not be found and is essential.'
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/pb/4p0s32g54dl1vg3s25kch71w0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/PyGObject/
```

This is what I get back. I have Python 3 and I use PyCharm. I tried to install PyGObject and I can not make it work. I have tried several approaches but nothing has worked. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question belongs in serverfault.com community, not here. This is a forum to support those who have written code.

Comment: `raise SystemExit, 'string'` is Python 2 only. That is why you get a SyntaxError exception. And as the error says: GIO is not found. Have you installed it? It should be bundled with GLib.